# How can I costumize the ToC for 2 different types of chapters?

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, chapters

I already have ((re)new)defined a 2nd type of the `\chapter` macro for I have two different types of chapters. But they have one counter, which appears for every chapter in ToC.
Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcounter {uberschrift}
\renewcommand \theuberschrift {\@arabic\c@uberschrift}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand\uberschrift{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi % Typ I
                                    \thispagestyle{fancy}%
                                    \global\@topnum\z@
                                    \@afterindentfalse
                                    \secdef\@uberschrift\@suberschrift}
\def\@uberschrift[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                                             \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                                             \refstepcounter{uberschrift}%
                                             \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                             {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                                    \else
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
                                    \fi
                                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{3\p@}}%
                                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{2\p@}}%
                                    \if@twocolumn
                                        \@topnewpage[\@makeuberschrifthead{#2}]%
                                    \else
                                        \@makeuberschrifthead{#2}%
                                        \@afterheading
                                    \fi}
\def\@makeuberschrifthead#1{%
\vspace*{-20\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries \thechapter\space   #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
}}
\def\@suberschrift#1{\if@twocolumn
                             \@topnewpage[\@makesuberschrifthead{#1}]%
                             \else
                                 \@makesuberschrifthead{#1}%
                                 \@afterheading
                             \fi}
\def\@makesuberschrifthead#1{%
\vspace*{-20\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries \thechapter\space   #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                                    \thispagestyle{fancy}
                                    \global\@topnum\z@
                                    \@afterindentfalse
                                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\typeout{\@chapapp   \thechapter.}      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}
         {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                                    \else
                    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                                    \fi
                                    \chaptermark{#1}%
            \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                                    \if@twocolumn
                        \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                                    \else
                                        \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                                        \@afterheading
                                    \fi}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{0\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
            \huge\bfseries \@chapapp \space \thechapter
            \par\nobreak
            \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
}}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                                 \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                             \else
                                 \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                                 \@afterheading
                             \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{-10\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
 \tableofcontent
\chapter{One}
 \lipsum[1]
\uberschrift{Two}
 \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

So I redefined `\chapter`for behaving in 2 different ways ("chapter" and "uberschrift"). The `\chapter`-chapter is supposed to come up *without* a number in my ToC, whereas the `\uberschrift`-chapter is supposed to come *with* a number.

Comment: Please tell us a bit more about the purpose of these two chapter-like sectioning instructions. Are both supposed to be generating numbered chapter-like headers, yet only one type will be numbered in the table of contents? And, are you hoping that someone will guess correctly what the (re)definitions of `\@uberschrift`, etc contain?

Comment: As of now, I hate to have to tell you, the purpose/objective of your posting is quite unclear. Please consider re-writing and clarifying your posting.

Comment: try packages minitoc or multitoc if you wont toc for per chapter different tocs..or just redefine chapter as "uberschrift" and use it as regular "chapter" and for unnumbered chapter use just \chapter* and addtotoc for unnumbered chapters

Comment: @Nepumuk: I am not sure that you have understood the difference between `\chapter` and `\chapter*`. If you would specify clearly **why** you want to change the chapter macro at all, this could be achieved much easier, I believe. Is it the spacings? Is it the total appearance (fonts/size etc.) The ToC - entries?

Comment: there is easy ways to do this, but you can try replace `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}` with `\addcontentsline{toc}{uberschrift}{#1}` in definition of `uberschrift` and then define `\l@uberschrift` by changing `\l@chapter` command.

Comment: @Mico First of all, I have to give a huge SORRY to you all for having noticed right now that I haven't ever needed the definition of `\uberschrift`. **I wanted `\chapter` and `\chapter*` to behave in different ways as they do normally (adjust space and chapterhead mostly) ; and the main thing is that `\chapter` appears as it does normally in the ToC and `\chapter*`appears in the same way, just without the number of the chapter**. Can I redefine the ToC-command that it does this? If so, I would throw out `\uberschrift` completely and just "add `\chapter` to the ToC-command". (Is it that easy?)

Comment: The thing is, I don't know what to redefine in `\newcommand\tableofcontents`. Do I even have to change it there? Or is it in `\def\@schapter#1`?

Comment: to add unmumbered chapter in toc just do in document: \chapter*{Foreword} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword} to redefine \chapter& appearence in document just post design what you want someone will help out.. i use memoir class for document...search and you'll find many examples how to redefine chapters..se for example this ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf